Conditional probablity of drwing tennis balls that were not used before for $2$ matches.
There are $15$ tennis balls in the box, $9$ of which have not yet been used. Two balls were drawn, a match was played with them and they were put back in the box. Then two balls were drawn again from the box and a match was played with them. Assuming that both balls in the second match were unused (both in the previous match and before), calculate the probability that both balls in the first match were also used for the first time.
$A$: 2 balls in match 1 were unused before, $\mathbb{P}(A) = \frac{{{9}\choose{2}}}{{{15}\choose{2}}}$
$B$: $2$ balls used in match $2$ were unused before, $\mathbb{P}(B) = \mathbb{P}(B_1) + \mathbb{P}(B_2)+ \mathbb{P}(B_3)$, where:

$B_1$: $2$ balls used in match $1$ were unused before - then $2$ balls used in match $2$ were unused before, $\mathbb{P}(B_1) = \frac{{{9}\choose{2}}}{{{15}\choose{2}}} \cdot \frac{{{7}\choose{2}}}{{{15}\choose{2}}}$
$B_2$: out of $2$ balls used in match $1$, one was unused before and one was used before - then $2$ balls used in match $2$ were unused before, $\mathbb{P}(B_2) = \frac{9 \cdot 6}{{{15}\choose{2}}} \cdot \frac{{{8}\choose{2}}}{{{15}\choose{2}}}$
$B_3$: $2$ balls used in match $1$ were used before - then $2$ balls used in match $2$ were unused before, $\mathbb{P}(B_3) = \frac{{{6}\choose{2}}}{{{15}\choose{2}}} \cdot \frac{{{9}\choose{2}}}{{{15}\choose{2}}}$

Therefore,
$\mathbb{P}(B) = \frac{{{9}\choose{2}}}{{{15}\choose{2}}} \cdot \frac{{{7}\choose{2}}}{{{15}\choose{2}}} + \frac{9 \cdot 6}{{{15}\choose{2}}} \cdot \frac{{{8}\choose{2}}}{{{15}\choose{2}}} + \frac{{{6}\choose{2}}}{{{15}\choose{2}}} \cdot \frac{{{9}\choose{2}}}{{{15}\choose{2}}}$
The probability that is to be calculated: $\mathbb{P}(A|B) = \frac{\mathbb{P}(A \cap B)}{\mathbb{P}(B)} = \frac{\mathbb{P}(B_1)}{\mathbb{P}(B)} = \frac{\frac{{{9}\choose{2}}}{{{15}\choose{2}}} \cdot \frac{{{7}\choose{2}}}{{{15}\choose{2}}}}{\frac{{{9}\choose{2}}}{{{15}\choose{2}}} \cdot \frac{{{7}\choose{2}}}{{{15}\choose{2}}} + \frac{9 \cdot 6}{{{15}\choose{2}}} \cdot \frac{{{8}\choose{2}}}{{{15}\choose{2}}} + \frac{{{6}\choose{2}}}{{{15}\choose{2}}} \cdot \frac{{{9}\choose{2}}}{{{15}\choose{2}}}}$
$
Is that correct?

Yes, I think it is correct.
